# How do you make a f# recursive function that return the character from the list?

Tags: list, recursion, f#

the f# recursive function should return the character from the list that corresponds to the smallest number on the list that is greater than the input number.

Ex: The f# recursive function should be like:

if I input:
something 0.05 [(0.1, '*'), (0.5, '@'), (1.0, '!')]

then its output must be:
'*'

if I input 
something 0.6 [(0.1, '*'), (0.5, '@'), (1.0, '!')]

then its output must be:
'!'

and if I input 
something 2.0 [(0.1, '*'), (0.5, '@'), (1.0, '!')]

then its output should be
' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let list =
    [ (0.1, '*')
      (0.5, '@')
      (1.0, '!') ]

let rec something index lst =
        match lst with
        | [] -> '\000'
        | h :: t -> 
            let value, chr = h
            if index <= value
            then chr
            else something index t

list 
|> List.sortBy fst // only needed if not already sorted by value
|> something 2.0
```

Comment: how do you make rec something returns '  ' (space with nothing at all)?                             ex: if I input something 2.0 [(0.1, '*'), (0.5, '@'), (1.0, '!')], then out put should be '  ';;

Comment: Unless a space or a non-printing character is good enough, then you will probably need to handle that when you output the results as a string. "" is an empty string, but '' is not allowed. Another approach would be to use a list of strings instead of a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky to iterate over the provided 'list'
I would've need to hard code the tuple elements
That I can of did at the end to make it a list

Unlike the provided sample that is

```
((float * char) * (float * char) * (float * char)) list
```

a tuple of tuples list with only 1 element

and Given that all elements are of the same 'kind'
I generalized it as a

```
(float*char) list
```

much easier to iterate and bit more generic

```ml
/// Note the absence of comma
/// it's a (float * char) list
let list =
    [ (0.1, '*')
      (0.5, '@')
      (1.0, '!') ]

/// type can't be inferred as parameter
type Tuples = ((float * char) * (float * char) * (float * char)) list

// Type ((float * char) * (float * char) * (float * char)) list
// Note the comma instead of a semicolon
let tuples = [ (0.1, '*'), (0.5, '@'), (1.0, '!') ]

/// Sort by numeric value
let sortByWeight = List.sortBy (fun (x, _) -> x)

/// quite generic recursive function
/// type can't be inferred
let rec isMatch (tuples: (float * char) list) index test =
    if index < tuples.Length then
        match tuples.[index] with
        | (weight, value) when weight > test -> value
        | _ -> isMatch tuples (index + 1) test
    else
        '\000' //can't type ''

/// helper to avoid messing up the index
/// and DRY
let find x list =
    isMatch (list |> sortByWeight) 0 x
    |> printf "%f -> %A\n" x

printf "With a List\n"

list |> find 0.05
list |> find 0.6
list |> find 2.0

printf "Now with Tuples\n"

/// type can't be inferred
let toList (tuples: Tuples) =
    let (a, b, c) = (tuples.Item 0)
    [ a; b; c ]

tuples |> toList |> find 0.05
tuples |> toList |> find 0.6
tuples |> toList |> find 2.0
```

It outputs

```
With a List
0.050000 -> '*'
0.600000 -> '!'
2.000000 -> '\000'
Now with Tuples
0.050000 -> '*'
0.600000 -> '!'
2.000000 -> '\000'
```

to the extra questions ...

The simplest and more generic is the non recursive (find)
(find1) is more traditional and less generic
(find2) Scott's recursive ,is more idiomatic
The all do the same, iterate compare and return a subproduct

```ml
let list =
    [ (0.1, '*')
      (0.5, '@')
      (1.0, '!') ]

/// non-recursive
let find test map list =
    match list |> List.tryFind test with
    | None -> map None
    | x -> Some(x).Value |> map

/// iterates
let rec find1 test result index (lst: 'a list) =
    if index < list.Length then
        match lst.[index] with
        | x when test x -> Some(x) |> result
        | _ -> find1 test result (index + 1) lst
    else
        result None

/// iterates , idiomatically
let rec find2 test result index lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> result None
    | head :: tail ->
        if test head then Some(head) |> result
        else find2 test result index tail

let greaterThanIndex index = fun (value, _) -> value > index

let map x =
    match x with
    | None -> '\000'
    | Some(_, chr) -> chr

printf "ctrl+c to quit!\n"

// the 'input function'?
match System.Console.ReadLine() with
| input ->
    match System.Double.TryParse input with
    | false, _ ->
        printf "%s: NaN! \n" input
    | _, index ->
        list
        |> find (greaterThanIndex index) map
        |> printf "find: %2.2f in %A = %c\n" index list
        // ...
        list
        |> find1 (greaterThanIndex index) map 0
        |> printf "find1: %2.2f in %A = %c\n" index list
        // ...
        list
        |> find2 (greaterThanIndex index) map index
        |> printf "find2: %2.2f in %A = %c\n" index list
```

Comment: Is there more simple way in rec function?

Comment: How do you write input function?

Comment: what do you mean with "input function" ? Console.Read ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your function does something like this:

1) Call itself (the recursive part) to find the best candidate in the tail of the list.

2) Compare the best candidate from step 1 to the head of the list, and ...

3) If the head of the list is a better solution than than the candidate from the tail, then use the head, otherwise use the tail candidate one.